Will an acquire operation prevent reordering if there's no corresponding release?
I'm working with atomic operations in a multi-threaded program in C++ and trying to understand how acquire semantics behave when used without a corresponding release. Specifically, I know that acquire is typically used with release to establish a synchronization point between threads, but what happens if there is no matching release?
My main question is:
If I use an atomic operation with acquire semantics, will it still prevent subsequent operations from being reordered before the acquire even if there is no preceding release?
I'm trying to understand if the acquire on its own will provide some guarantee about memory ordering within the same thread or if it's only meaningful when paired with a release.
Any clarification on this would be appreciated!

Why would the memory ordering be important if you only have 1 thread ?

@AhmedAEK Imagine a multi-threaded application where a thread could (conditionally) performs a write and release but never does. On the one hand the answer is moot - if acquire 'acquires' nothing what difference would re-ordering make?
On the other at Compiler level it can't (logically) determine if a Release will or won't occur so in compiled code terms surely must respect the Acquire boundary for re-ordering.

Whether the reordering happens or not is irrelevant. Because there's no way to observe that. Schrodinger's code, man. XD

"but what happens if there is no matching release?" - great chance of deadlock.

On a single thread you can safely assume that statements are executed in a way that matches your C++ statements. No surprises (that doesn't mean the compiler can be smart, and reorder assembly instructions, do pipeline optimization etc) but it will not be observable to you.

Acquire and release operations are only required to prevent [observable] reordering relative to themselves (for example write operations before an acquire/release can't be reordered to be after that acquire/release).    Omitting a release does not affect that.   The main danger of a missing release is deadlock - for example, if two threads both seek to acquire a resource, and one of them neglects to release it.


If I use an atomic operation with acquire semantics, will it still prevent subsequent operations from being reordered before the acquire even if there is no preceding release?

Reordering is an implementation detail. It is not part of the specification of the memory model.
The only thing relevant in the memory model is whether or not evaluations happen-before one another. For evaluations in a single thread an evaluation that is sequenced-before another also happens-before another. Usually there is no happens-before relation between evaluations in different threads. Such a relation can be established by two evaluations that synchronize-with one another.
An acquire operation on an atomic object is specified to synchronize-with a release operation on the same atomic object if the former reads the value stored by the latter in the atomic's modification order. (And there are other situations where a synchronizes-with is established.)
If there is only an acquire operation without a release operation, then there can't be any synchronizes-with being established and the behavior of the program is exactly as if the acquire operation was a relaxed operation.

In an actual implementation of compiler and CPU this specification will be implemented by enforcing certain evaluation orders that are otherwise unobservable and so it may be that the acquire operation on the atomic will enforce some specific ordering in the emitted code, but that is unobservable to you and an implementation detail that could, in theory at least, change.


If I use an atomic operation with acquire semantics, will it still prevent subsequent operations from being reordered before the acquire.

No, not all operations. an acquire only prevents subsequent memory reads from being re-ordered before it, while reads before it can be re-ordered after it, and writes before or after it can be re-ordered before or after it, you cannot use atomics to force order on generic instructions
Same with the release only affecting write operations before it, it won't affect any reads before or after it, or the writes that happen after it, which can be reordered before it, they can even be ordered before the write instructions that were before the atomic.
The only guarantee you have is that writes before the release should be visible to reads after the acquire of the same atomic.
